# Automatically turn off VPN for select website/IP

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, unix, ip-routing

Using a VPN for privacy and security on a Unix machine. There are a few sites that I can only access through my whitelisted IP for work. Is there a way to automatically turn off my VPN (or route traffic using my static IP) when accessing certain websites?  Hoping to do this outside of application settings and in config files.

Comment: It is unclear whether you are using a VPN on a system that is not supposed to have one, in which case it's off-topic, for circumventing employer network regulations, or if it's a private computer that you can do what you want with, in which case it's off-topic because it's not about systems administration in a business environment. I'm voting to move it, but I'd also suggest that you edit your question to include some information about the configuration of your VPN software.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to add routes for the whitelisted IPs in your OS configuration. For example, if the destination is `192.168.100.100` and your ISP gateway/router is`192.168.1.1`, you use:

```
route add 192.168.100.100 gw 192.168.1.1
```